# Session em select

Tags: php

O `select` está sendo carregado pelo `$view->montarComboAreasNoticia()`, o que estou querendo é que crie uma `session` para salvar a opção que eu escolhi quando eu voltar novamente para a pagina de seleção do `select`.

**Código**:

```
<select name="FArea" id="select2">
          <option value="0">
                   <?=translate("Todas")?>
          </option>
          <?$view->montarComboAreasNoticia(); ?>
</select>`
```

Comment: Bem você deve colocar o código do método `montarComboAreasNoticia()`, a modificação terá que ficar dentro deve com algum IF simples deve resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Só abrir a sessão em todas as páginas que você queira retirar a informação:

```
session_start();
```

E atribuir o valor na variável de sessão:

```
$_SESSION['opcao'] = $opcao
```